# Why doesn't the banana experiment change world lines in Steins;Gate?

Tags: steins-gate

In *Steins;Gate*, when Okabe finally decides to use one banana instead of the whole bunch to experiment on the PhoneWave (Name subject to change), the single banana returns to the bunch in gel-bana form. With this, they finally manage to observe the time-travelling effect of the PhoneWave (Name subject to change), effectively sending the banana back in time.

Later they figure out that for each second set on the PhoneWave (Name subject to change) they send items or messages one hour back in time.

Since they always set the timer to 120 seconds, wouldn't that always change the world line in these situations? Because they send the banana 5 days back, it would always default to a world line where Mayuri doesn't buy a banana bunch with a gel-bana attached to it, making it enough of a change to move between lines.

Is this ever addressed in the anime or visual novel?

Comment: I think trying to make "Steins;Gate" consistent is about as hopeless as making "Primer" consistent.

Comment: I think so too, but one can always hope hahaha

Answer (score 1):

It's simply too little to overcome convergence. Add to that the fact that Reading Steiner is actually

> *universal to everyone*, with differences in sensitivity

It means that the world was rebuilt, but everyone at the lab just remembers the line they came from.

My personal understanding is that Mayushii could have been too ditzy to notice the bananas she was buying were jellified.

It's said that that around that time there is a massive attractor field.

Just like later on with the lottery ticket, the worldlines converged and Reading Steiner didn't seem to activate (a bit like a fast-forwarded git merge).

With convergence, minor changes to the timeline behave as if they had always been there, but people may not remember it because of Reading Steiner.